# Angular 4 Conditional styling

Tags: angular

I have this html code which works great:

```
<button class="button-style standard-button button-blue" (click)="onOkClick()"
[ngClass]="{'disabled': !hasUnsavedNotes()}" [disabled]="!hasUnsavedNotes()">
Save and close
</button>
```

My question is how do I change class="button-style standard-button button-blue" to class="button-style standard-button button-grey" when hasUnsavedNotes() returns false? Or simply how do I change the button back color when its disabled? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just do this little adjustment:

```
<button 
    [class.button-blue]="!hasUnsavedNotes()"
    [class.button-grey]="hasUnsavedNotes()"
    class="button-style standard-button" 
    (click)="onOkClick()"
    [disabled]="!hasUnsavedNotes()">
    Save and close
</button>
```

*[class.button-blue]="!hasUnsavedNotes()"*

will add `button-blue` css class when `!hasUnsavedNotes()`returns `true` and will remove this class when `!hasUnsavedNotes()`returns `false`. Is the same to:

*[class.button-grey]="hasUnsavedNotes()"*

You can remove the [disabled] directive if you wish.

Here is a helpful list of "tricks" to use in Angular: [Angular - Cheat Sheet](https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet)

Comment: Thanks, much simpler than my approach below.  Any idea how I can change the cursor from a hand to the default when the button is disabled?

Comment: You can style it with css 3.0 `:disabled` status selector, like this: `.my-btn:disabled { cursor: default }`

Answer (score 2):

[ngClass]="{'button-blue': hasUnsavedNotes(), 'button-grey': !hasUnsavedNotes()}"

Comment: How do I implement your suggestion along with [ngClass]="{'disabled': !hasUnsavedNotes()}"

Comment: ngClass takes in an object, just separate the value with a comma like I did above

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way but this solution worked:

```
<button *ngIf="hasUnsavedNotes() else disable_button"
    class="button-style standard-button button-blue"
    (click)="onOkClick()"
    [ngClass]="{'disabled': !hasUnsavedNotes()}" 
    [disabled]="!hasUnsavedNotes()">
          Save and close
</button>
<ng-template #disable_button>
    <button class="button-style standard-button button-disabled"
        (click)="onOkClick()"
        [ngClass]="{'disabled': !hasUnsavedNotes()}" 
        [disabled]="!hasUnsavedNotes()">
            Save and close
    </button>
</ng-template>
```